# Hibernate: Enabling useAffectedRows causes OptimisticLockExceptions for no-op updates

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I need to update a Java app so that SQL updates rely on a count of "affected rows" instead of "found rows" (long story). I ran the app's test suite that uses the MySQL database with `useAffectedRows=true` and sure enough, there were many failures with this error:

```
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

The actual cause seems to be this exception:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

As best I can tell, this is only happening when a database object is created and saved to the database in one transaction, then saved again later in a new transaction and no fields have changed (i.e. a no-op). This situation occurs most often with cascading saves. If I refresh the object or change a field value on the object before saving it in the second transaction, everything works fine.

I'm assuming this is happening because enabling `useAffectedRows` causes those types of updates to return a `0` for the row count because nothing was actually updated, so Hibernate thinks the update failed.

Is there another setting I need to configure to make Hibernate okay with "no-op updates," or do I need to change how transactions are handled in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Connector/J Configuration Properties](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

> **useAffectedRows**
>
> Don't set the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag when connecting to the server
>   (**not JDBC-compliant, will break most applications that rely on "found"
>   rows vs. "affected rows" for DML statements**), but does cause "correct"
>   update counts from "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" statements to
>   be returned by the server.

And [related](https://github.com/vitessio/vitess/issues/5041)

> The Vitess JDBC driver defaults useAffectedRows to true, unlike MySQL.
>   Notably, **this breaks hibernate's saveOrUpdate() and replicate()
>   methods** because they expect the result to be matched rows.

Based on some Googling, you're unlikely to get an easy fix. You're the one that's doing non-standard things, and as it would be unwise for Hibernate developers to try to take into account all sorts of weird quirks (not to mention that this probably affects the whole design), you'll have to either come up with some really ugly hacks or try to get rid of the useAffectedRows property.

Comment: I suspected that this was likely the case, but documentation around how the `useAffectedRows` setting affects Hibernate is virtually non-existent so I couldn't be sure. Thanks for the info.